# Можно ли создать объект через конструктор, используя обобщенный тип

Tags: c#

У меня есть метод, который считывает файл и возвращает список студентов. Мне надо считать другой файл, в котором хранится информация про факультеты (конструктор класса Факультета принимает такие же аргументы, что и у класса Студенты). Можно ли реализовать это в одном методе, и если можно, то как?

```
    public static List<Student> ReadStudentFile(string path)
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        string temp;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default))
            {
                while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        students.Add(new Student(temp.Split(' ')));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return students;
    }
```

Конструкторы:

```
    public Student(string[] args)
    {
        surname = args[0];
        department = args[1];
        grants = UInt32.Parse(args[2]);
        marks = args.Skip(3).Select(t=>Int32.Parse(t)).ToArray();
        if (marks.Length > 5 || marks.Length < 3)
            throw new Exception();
    }
    public Department(string[] args)
    {
        surnameOfDean = args[0];
        name = args[1];
        numberPhone = args[2];
    }
```

Comment: Приведите конструктор класса `Student` и факультета.

Comment: добавил конструкторы

Comment: Можно, надо передавать фабричный метод для создания сущности

Comment: Никогда не используйте кодировку Default: код сломается на машине с другой кодировкой по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
public static List<T> ReadFile<T>(string path, Func<string[], T> del)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default))
        {
            string temp;
            while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(del(temp.Split()));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Использование:

```
var students = ReadFile("...", x => new Student(x));
var departments = ReadFile("...", x => new Department(x));
```

Также можно использовать рефлексию, но она медленная. Смотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/840261/5045688